# Error al registrar usuario detached entity passed to persist: SpringBootJPADATA.entidad.Rol

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

tengo un problema a la hora de relacionar la tabla de "usuarios" con la tabla de "roles" cuando lanzo una consulta con Postman me tira el error en forma de JSON dentro de un proyecto API REST:

```
{
    "marcaDeTiempo": "2022-03-30T13:51:46.710+00:00",
    "mensaje": "detached entity passed to persist: SpringBootJPADATA.entidad.Rol; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: SpringBootJPADATA.entidad.Rol",
    "detalles": "uri=/api/auth/registrar"
}
```

He estado investigando sobre el error y he comprado que es causado por relacionar entidades bidireccionales, he probado varios comandos dentro de la entidad usuarios pero no hay forma de hacer que funcione. Os pego la clase Rol y la clase Usuario:

```
package SpringBootJPADATA.entidad;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;


@Entity
//agregamos dos restriccionescon la anotacion uniqueConstraint para que no se puedan repetir
@Table(name = "usuarios", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username" }),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" }) })
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String nombre;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "usuarios_roles",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Rol> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Rol> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Ahora la clase Rol:

```
package SpringBootJPADATA.entidad;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Rol {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String nombre;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Rol() {
        super();
    }

}
```

He comprobado los nombres de los campos entre otras cosas, deduzco que la problemática radica dentro de la clase Usuario al declarar su relación con el la entidad roles con el atributo  Set< Rol > roles.
Ahora añado el controlador REST que hace el registro de usuario en BBDD:

```
package SpringBootJPADATA.controlador;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import SpringBootJPADATA.dto.LoginDTO;
import SpringBootJPADATA.dto.RegistroDTO;
import SpringBootJPADATA.entidad.Rol;
import SpringBootJPADATA.entidad.Usuario;
import SpringBootJPADATA.repositorio.RolRepositorio;
import SpringBootJPADATA.repositorio.UsuarioRepositorio;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthControlador {
    // Todo componente de Spring (@Bean por ejemplo) se puede inyectar en las clases
    // para su uso específico

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepositorio usuarioRepositorio;

    @Autowired
    private RolRepositorio rolRepositorio;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/iniciarSesion")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.getUsernameOrEmail(), loginDTO.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Ha iniciado sesion con éxito", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/registrar")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registrarUsuario(@RequestBody RegistroDTO registroDTO) {

        if (usuarioRepositorio.existsByUsername(registroDTO.getUsername())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Ese nombre de usuario ya existe", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if (usuarioRepositorio.existsByEmail(registroDTO.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Ese email ya existe", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setNombre(registroDTO.getNombre());
        usuario.setUsername(registroDTO.getUsername());
        usuario.setEmail(registroDTO.getEmail());
        usuario.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registroDTO.getPassword()));
        Rol roles = rolRepositorio.findByNombre("ROLE_ADMIN").get();
        // singleton es una coleccionde 1 posicion
        usuario.setRoles(Collections.singleton(roles));
        usuarioRepositorio.save(usuario);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Usuario registrado correctamente", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

si tienen alguna sugerencia que me aclare como relacionar estas dos entidades de la forma correcta lo agradezco de antemano

Comment: Creo que el error no es por causa de la ddefinición de las entidades, deberías compartir el código del ¿servicio? donde ocurre el error (desde donde se intenta guardar los datos)

Comment: se guarda desde un paquete controlador de autenticaciones, edito la pregunta para pegar el controlador y que veas la llamada del método

Comment: sustituye `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` por `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` en Rol

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema viene dado porque tienes puesto CascadeType.ALL en la relación entre la entidad Usuario y entidad Rol: eso significa que cualquier operación que se haga sobre la entidad Usuario se debe realizar también sobre la entidad Rol. Por ejemplo, si borraras un usuario, estarías borrando también la entidad Rol si no hubiera más usuarios asociados a la misma.

Puesto que Rol es una Entidad que no depende de Usuario realmente (es una característica *estática*, podrías tener cero Usuarios y aún así las entidades Rol deberían estar presentes), las operaciones que hagas sobre un usuario no deberían afectar nunca a Rol.

Por otro lado, es habitual que los Roles se guarden en base de datos como una columna más de tipo text/varchar en la misma tabla de usuarios, teniendo un enum con los posibles valores en la aplicación. No aporta mucho crear una tabla sólo para guardar los nombres de los posibles valores, ya que cualquier nuevo rol suele implicar también nueva lógica para gestionar sus permisos.

Comment: Hola Pablo, acabo de encontrar el fallo, la disposición que tengo está correcta, el fallo estaba en que en la base de datos tenía creada dos columnas que no debían estar ahí en la tabla intermedia de la relación muchos a muchos, de todas formas muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Saludos

Comment: En ese caso no marques la respuesta como "correcta", puede liar a otros que lleguen aquí con algún problema similar